# mongodb river for elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose, elasticsearch

Is there any official mongodb river available for elasticsearch ? I am using mongodb in node.js through the module mogoose.
I have seen one in http://www.matt-reid.co.uk/blog_post.php?id=68

Is this the correct one ? It says unofficial though...

Edit:
looks like, https://github.com/aparo/elasticsearch has inbuilt mongodb plugin.. Is there any doc available about how to configure this with mongodb and how mongodb pushes data for indexing to elasticsearch?

Answer (score 4):

There is a new MongoDB river on github:

https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

according to the code you can specify several things but there is no separate doc (expect one mailing list discussion):

https://github.com/aparo/elasticsearch/blob/master/plugins/river/mongodb/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/river/mongodb/MongoDBRiver.java

https://github.com/aparo/elasticsearch/blob/master/plugins/river/mongodb/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/river/mongodb/MongoDBRiverTest.java

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really the answer you're looking for. I looked at building this mongo river but I found some discussion on it having some memory leaks and I didn't want to fiddle with Java code. I wrote my own mongo->ES importer using the bulk API.

It's a work in progress, so feel free to contribute! :)

https://github.com/orenmazor/elastic-search-loves-mongo

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There is a new MongoDB river on github:

https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb

For Further Explanation You can follow below steps:

**Step.1:** -Install

```
ES_HOME/bin/plugin -install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments/1.4.0 
ES_HOME/bin/plugin -install richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/1.4.0
```

**Step.2:** `-Restart Elasticsearch`

```
ES_HOME/bin/service/elasticsearch restart
```

**Step.3:** -Enable replica sets in mongodb

go to **mongod.conf** & Add line

```
replSet=rs0
```

save & Exit

Restart mongod

**Step.4:** -Tell elasticsearch to index the “person” collection in `testmongo` database by issuing the following command in your terminal

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_river/mongodb/_meta' -d '{ 
    "type": "mongodb", 
    "mongodb": { 
        "db": "testmongo", 
        "collection": "person"
    }, 
    "index": {
        "name": "mongoindex", 
        "type": "person" 
    }
}'
```

**Step.5:** -add some data to the mongodb through mongo terminal

```
use testmongo
var p = {firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe"}
db.person.save(p)
```

**Step.6:** -Use this command to search the data

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/mongoindex/_search?q=firstName:John'
```

**NOTE:**

```
DELETE /_river

DELETE/_mongoindex
```

Again run this command,

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_river/mongodb/_meta' -d '{ 
    "type": "mongodb", 
    "mongodb": { 
        "db": "testmongo", 
        "collection": "person"
    }, 
    "index": {
        "name": "mongoindex", 
        "type": "person" 
    }
}'
```

**Step.7:** -See HQ Plugin

In `mongoindex`, you will get your data.